# ¿Es posible clonar un Date en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

¿Es posible clonar un `Date()` en *Javascript*? Es decir, que a partir de una variable de fecha, crear otra variable que tenga la misma fecha.

En el siguiente código se puede ver que al comparar `fecha_1` y `fecha_2` da `false`.

```js
var fecha_1 = new Date()
var fecha_2 = new Date()
console.log("Son fechas "+(fecha_1==fecha_2?"iguales":"diferentes")+".")
```

Sé que está comparando objetos diferentes y al no ser de tipo primitivo por eso da `false`, pero quisiera saber si se puede crear una fecha con los mismos valores que `fecha_1`, es decir, año, día, o incluso nanosegundos (milisegundos, o lo que sea). Tiene que tener exactamente los datos de la primera fecha.

Además quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de comprobar si son iguales, en términos de tiempo.

Nota: Si es posible, que funcione tanto en *Chrome* como en *Firefox*, ya que me di cuenta que actúan de forma diferente ante el manejo de fechas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes **clonar objetos de tipo Date en Javascript** de la siguiente forma:

```
var original = new Date();
var copy = new Date(original);
```

Los objetos siempre te van a dar que son distintos porque, obviamente, son objetos distintos. Sin embargo, puedes comprobar que el valor es exactamente el mismo:

```js
var original = new Date();
var copy = new Date(original);
console.log("Original: " + original + " - " + original.getTime());
console.log("Copy    : " + copy + " - " + copy.getTime())
console.log("Iguales: " + (original.getTime() == copy.getTime()))
```

Comment: comparar los getTime es un super buen criterio. Me gustó una respuesta que no se diera tantas vueltas intentando hacer un deepEqual.